# How one derives significance test for pearsons correlation coefficient?

Tags: statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I am exploring statistics and probability. What upsets me, only ready to use algorithms are present in the books. But no example how one derives a significance test, where from the test statistics come from etc. At the moment I am interesten in Pearsons coefficient significance test, but really derivation of any popular test will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

A rigorous paper on the correlation test is [here](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1909612?uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21104671709553).

More generally, any hypothesis test is derived using a very basic strategy:

1. Formulate the null hypothesis $H_0$ as a statement about a [*statistic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistic#Properties)
2. Pick an underlying distribution for the data (or decide you are doing a nonparametric test)
3. Determine the [sampling distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_distribution) of the statistic if we assume $H_0$ is true.
4. Determine the rejection region from the sampling distribution.

How do you choose a test statistic? That is the *art* of designing a good test, and always an area of active research!